# How to prove if $n$ is prime and $n | a^2$ then $n | a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

My professor assigned this for homework but I don't understand how to connect the dots. He suggested using the fact that $\gcd (x,y) \cdot \operatorname{lcm} (x,y) = xy$ but I'm not sure how that's relevant.

Comment: Strong Hint: Squaring $a$ does not add any new prime factors.

Comment: So you already know (some) properties of gcd and lcm, but you don't yet know the fundamental theorem of arithmetic / uniqueness of prime factorizations?

Comment: He has shown us how to use the FTA and did suggest to use it to prove this proof but I haven't fully grasped how to use the FTA in any of my proofs yet. Still sinking in.

Comment: Well, *one* definition of prime is that $p\mid ab$ implies $p\mid a\lor p\mid b$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers sure are technical for such a conceptually simple question.

$a$ can be factored uniquely into primes:

$$a=p_1...p_n$$

So $a^2$ looks like this:

$$a^2=p_1...p_np_1...p_n$$

Because prime factorization is unique, if $n$ divides $a^2$, that means $n$ is one of the $p_i$. In more detail, if $n$ divides $a^2$, then we can write $a^2=nx$ for some $x$. Factoring $x$ into primes, we get a new factorisation for $a^2$ including the prime $n$, and since this factorization must be the same as the original one (up to rearranging the factors), $n$ must be one of the $p_i$. So therefore it divides $a$.

The point is just that squaring doesn't introduce any new primes into the factorization, so if a prime is in there after squaring, it had to be in there before squaring too.

Comment: This is already remarked in my answer (see also the comments to the question).

Comment: @BillDubuque I think saying "it implies the prime divisor property" is a bit of a grand way of putting something so simple, especially for a beginning student.

Comment: But the Prime Divisor Proper is the essence of the matter here, and the sooner one grasps that simple concept the better a commmand one will have over number theory of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ (or any UFD). The PDP is equivalent to *uniqueness* of prime factorization (this being a special case of the easy direction of that equivalence)

Comment: Do you even need unique factorisation ? Suppose $a^2$ = $p_1.p_2...q_1.q_2....$ If n is prime and "always" divides ${a^2}$ then n must be one of the factors $p_i$ or $q_i$ so that n one of the factors in some factorisation of $a$ and so n divides a.

Comment: @Tom This can fail in non-UFDs, so you will need to use uniqueness or some closely related property. How are you deducing that "n must be..." if not by uniqueness (or some equivalent)?

Comment: @BillDubuque I included more details at the "handwavy" part. What I think you're forgetting is that, yes formal reasoning with things like the PDP is important, but not *before* grasping the siutation intuitively. I'm sure you yourself apply intuitive reasoning like the above constantly, even if you then replace it with a formal argument. The OP will not be well served by being trained to do arithmetic solely by the application of rules without ever having been made aware of the "intuitive" content of unique factorization.

Comment: @Jack That looks better. I agree that one needs the intuitive understanding too, but that needs to be done very carefully here because we have so much empirical intuitive knowledge of integer arithmetic that it is sometimes difficult for beginning students to separate *empirical* from *logical* deduction.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque. Thanks for clarification: I think I see it. If not UFD then n can be part of some altogether different factorisation of $a^2$ which has nothing in common with a *P* or *Q* factorisation of *a*.

Comment: @Tom Yes, that and many other strange things occur in non-UFDs - things that greatly challenge our arithmetical intuition (developed almost exclusively in UFDs).

Comment: Now that you've added the missing details to obtain a complete and rigorous proof, note that the result is essentially the same as the standard proof of PDP in my remark (for the special case $\,a=b).\,$ The reason that this PDP property is abstracted out is that this is the key property needed for generalizations [(prime ideals).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal)

Answer (score 2):

prime $p|ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|b$.

so, if $a=b$, $p|a^2$, we must have $p|a$

If $p\nmid a$, then $(p,a)=1$. Bézout's identity

$$px+ay=1$$

so

$$pxb+aby=b$$

we get $p|b$

Answer (score 1):

Said gcd, lcm law does imply the Prime Divisor Property (PDP): $ $ prime $\,p\mid ab,\ p\nmid a\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid b$

**Hint** $\ $ By said law, $\,\gcd(a,p)=1\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{{\rm lcm}(a,p)=ap},\,$ so $\,a,p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{ap}\mid ab\,$ so $\,\ldots$

**Remark** $\ $ If *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations is already known then the PDP follows easily: $ $ if $\,p\mid ab\,$ then $\,pc = ab.\,$ Appending $\,p\,$ to the prime factorization of $\,c\,$ yields one prime factorization of $\ pc = ab.\,$ Appending the prime factorizations of $\,a,b\,$ yields another. By uniqueness, they have equal sets of primes, $ $ i.e. with $\,\cal P(k) =$ set of prime factors of $\,k,\,$ we have that $\,\{p\}\cup\cal P(c) = \cal P(a)\cup \cal P(b),\,$ so $\,p\in\cal P(a)\,$ or $\,p\in\cal P(b),\,$ so $\,p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b\ \ $  **QED**

Yours is the special case $\ b = a\ $ in PDP, $ $ i.e. prime $\ p\mid a^2\Rightarrow\, p\mid a.\ $ An obvious indcution extends the proof to a product of any number of factors, i.e. prime $\,p\mid a_1\cdots a_n\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a_i\,$ for some $\,i.\,$ Said in words: $ $  *if a prime divides a product then it divides some factor of the product*.