# Proof: $^2 + 2$ isn't divisible by 4 for all integers n

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I assumed by contradiction that $n^2 + 2 = 4k$, where k is any integer.
$n^2 = 4k - 2$, so $n^2 = 2(2k-1)$. This means $n^2$ is even, so n is even, but we assumed this is true for all integers n, but it isn't true for odd integers, which is a contradiction.

......

Is this correct ?

Comment: No, that's not correct. Your assumption was that $n^2+2$ is divisible by $4$ for a specific $n$, but for all $n$.

Comment: No - your argument would be the same for $n^2-8$, but $6^2-8$ is divisible by $4$.  [You have also used $n^2-2$ in the title and $n^2+2$ in the body, though correcting that would not change the main point]

Comment: the exact question wording was: For every integer n$, 4$ doesn't divide ($n^2 + 2$).

Comment: $(2n)^2+2=4n^2+2$ and $(2n+1)^2+2=4n^2+4n+3$

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a mixing up of "all" and "some". You have proven that it cannot be true that for *every* integer $n$, $n^2-2$ is divisible by 4. (In fact you've shown it's not true if $n$ is odd, because then $n^2-2$ is odd.) But the question is about proving that it is not true that for *any* integer $n$, $n^2-2$ is divisible by 4.

That is, the claim is wrong if you can find even one value of $n$ such that $n^2-2$ is divisible by $4$. And to prove the claim true, you need to make an argument about every single value of $n$.

You've made a good argument for odd $n$, so now consider even $n$. Why can't $n^2-2$ be a multiple of $4$ if $n$ is even? (Try some small examples like $n=2$, $n=4$, $n=6$ if you get stuck.)

Answer (score 1):

No.  You didn't assume it was true for all integers.  In order to prove something is true for all integers, and use contradiction, you assume it's false for *one* integer.  Then you show that even for this one integer, it doesn't work.

You correctly conclude that $n$ must be even.  That means $n=2m$.  Plug that in and see if you can get your contradiction.

Comment: Yeah you end up with 2$ = 4k - $4a^2, which means RHS = a multiple of 4. LHS must also be a multiple of 4, which 2 isn't = contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your reasoning has been explained well by other users, so I will complement the other answers by providing two alternative solutions: one direct, and one by contradiction

#### Alternative solution :

**Lemma**: any perfect square leaves a remainder of either $0 \ \text{or}\  1$ on division by $4$. (If you know modular arithmetic, you may recognise it to be the fact that any perfect square $a^2$ satisfies $a\equiv 0\ \text{or}\ 1\bmod 4$ where $a\in \mathbb Z_+$).

**Proof of lemma:** If $a$ is odd then we can write $a=2n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Then, $a^2=4n^2$ which is completely divisible by $4$ and thus leaves the remainder of $0$ upon dividing by $4$.
 If $a$ is odd, thn $a=2n+1$ and so $a^2=4(n^2+n)+\fbox{$\color{red}1$}$ and so always leaves a remainder of $1$ upon division by $4$. 
Since the union of the sets of odd numbers and the sets of even numbers give us the set of positive integers, hence proved.

***By the lemma***, $a^2+2$ leaves a remainder of either $1\ \text{or}\ 2$ when divided by $4$ ( s $a$ is even or odd respectively) so is never divisible by $4$. $\blacksquare$
**_______________________________________**

#### **PROOF BY CONTRADICTION (alternative)**:

Suppose there exists such a positive integer $m$ for which $m^2+2$ has the audacity to be fully divisible by $4$. Now, a number divisible by 4 must necessarily be even, and therefore $m^2+2$ is even.

If $m^2+2$ is even, then $m^2$ must also be even (make sure you can rigorously explain why). This implies that $2|m^{\color{magenta}2}$.

Thus, we have, $2|m$. (For a proper reasoning as to why, refer to this page: [How to prove if $n$ is prime and $n | a^2$ then $n | a$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768955/how-to-prove-if-n-is-prime-and-n-a2-then-n-a)) Thus $m$ is even and can be written as $m=2n$ where $n$ is another positive integer. If so, then $m^2=4n^2$ is divisible by $4$ and hence, $m^2+2$ always leaves a remainder of $2$ when divided by $4$.

This implies that $m^2+2$ is ***not*** divisible by $4$, which is a contradiction. Thus no such $m$ exists. $\blacksquare$